# Location Background - Network Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to post data on background and I want to receive response from in regular interval that so that I am trying to use CLLocation Manager . But didUpdateToLocation method calling only once.
Please suggest me !

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackgroundUIApplication *)application
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_ QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //Do the work associated with the task
        // code for Posting Data Here
        NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}

- (void)locationManagerCLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocationCLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocationCLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Location Change");
}
```

This Method Call Only Once.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, and you should be happy what delegate received message at least once. There is no code which will delay application suspending in your background execution code. Also this kind of code can work about 10 minutes and will be killed by system.

If you need to track user location in background, than maybe you just set this mode for application background operation in **Info.plist** (**UIBackgroundModes** and add option **location**) and your app won't be suspended (only in case of heavy memory usage)